# Docker push local image under specified tag name

Tags: docker

I need to push Docker image from my local machine to my https://hub.docker.com repository under the specified tag name.

Locally I have the following image:

```
REPOSITORY        TAG                IMAGE ID     CREATED       SIZE
repo1/private    image1              29234rs8dsf  5 months ago  1.07GB
```

Hot to push this image under the specified tag(not `latest`, for example, `testtag1`) under my https://hub.docker.com repository `inttest/myimage` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood the question correctly, you can do it with following 3 steps -

1. TAG your local image to dockerhub repo image -

   `$ docker tag repo1/private:image1 inttest/myimage:testtag1`
2. Login to your dockerhub account using `docker login`
3. Push your dockerhub repo tagged image -

   `$ docker push inttest/myimage:testtag1`